# When using activity.recreate() screen flashes black for 0,5 secs

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When using activity.recreate() screen flashes black for 0,5 secs, is there anyways you can solve this so it doesen't blink. Or make the whole screen fadeout to black before using activity.recreate()?

Comment: why do you use .recreate()?

Comment: I have a app where i have this so called mode where private data is hidden, so I recreate the activity so the data on the screen is reloaded. I also could make everything that I don't want to be visible in this mode hidden(when I enable this mode with a button) but if I do a .recreate() it's much less code. Because I check when I load the data per item if this mode is on.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try to make 2 layouts, 1 with hiidden views and the other has all elements visible, and use `setContentView(layoutId);` to switch between them, if you have listeners on UI elements move the set listeners from `onCraete()` to `onResume()` and call it upon layout switching

Comment: This is not going to work for me because I have a Activity where I have 1 mainlayout in. When I press on a tab in the actionbar it loads a fragment in the mainlayout, the fragments handles the layout.

Comment: I have made a superclass for my fragments with two abstract functions. I put my fragment when I switch to one in a global variable in the activity and when I turn on that mode I call the function in the superclass to hide views!